# How do I disable a manufacturer without deleting it

Tags: magento-1.7

I need to temporary disable a manufacturer without deleting it completely
Is this possible?

Comment: you mean product attribute ?

Comment: What I need to do is hide the products this manufacturer has listed on the site?? I don't want to delete them - so if that means an attribute then great. I was looking at the attribute but it only has a delete button and not a disable. There are 93 pages of products so it's not easy to go through each item and disable them. Thanks

Comment: yes maybe I want to hide the products that the manufacturer has listed without deleting them all. when i looked at attributes it showed only a delete button ?? I want to disable them or hide them

Comment: Do you have database access?  It would be relatively easy to do from there.

Comment: Probably what you're looking for is the addition of a `manufacturer` column in the admin product grid, that way you can just select all the products that have a certain manufacturer and then disable those products. There are a number of solutions available that will do this.

Answer (score 1):

The way pspahn described is the way I would go too.

I would write a script, but it doesn't matter. To deactivate all products by a single manufacturer, you have to filter them and then set the status to disabled.

There are two ways to do this:

## add manufacturer to product grid

There are plenty of extensions to add manufacturer to product grid, I would use [GridControl](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/GridControl)

## just write a script

```
require 'Mage.php';
Mage::app();

// the id can be looked up in the backend, just use Firebug or WebDeveloperToolbar and check for the value entry in the select of manufacturer
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
//    ->setWebsiteId(12) // if you don't set your status on default scope, 
                         //this is needed for website scopr
//    ->setStoreId(12)   // and this for store view scope
    ->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', ID_OF_YOUR_MANUFACTURER);

foreach($collection as $product) {
    $product->setStatus(\Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
    $product->save();
}
```

Depending on where you set the status, you habe to loop over all the websites or storeviews too, to set the status on the correct scope.